# Is text in datalist optional,and can the value replace it?

Tags: html, forms, input, datalist

Do we only need a value with datalist, and not text between the tags?

Answer (score 0):

According to examples in [MDN - `datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) it doesn't need any text.